# Effort to enhance

Tags: domain-driven-design, modeling, anemic-domain-model

The question is from the from the patterns of enterprise application architecture by Fowler.

My effort to enhance formula = d x r + c

- d number domain definitions(classes)
- r replication of definitions
- c complexity
  constant

But having a hard time about justifying it for the table module pattern growing exponentially as there is not much replication of definitions at that part.

Why does table module effort to enhance grow exponentially ?

[image]

**References**

- Book
  [http://www.amazon.com/Patterns-Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Martin/dp/0321127420](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420)
- Domain Model
  http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html
- Table Module
  http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableModule.html

Comment: I doubt the graph is based on an actual formula. It's probably just based on experience.

Comment: People rely on these staff J. But it could be just hot air.... Not sure how to prove it or disprove it.

Comment: "Not sure how to prove it or disprove it" Like I said... experience and I'm sure Fowler didn't rely only on it's own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's [favourite diagram of Dino Esposito](http://www.pdf-archive.com/2015/08/22/architecting-implementing-ddd-patterns/preview/page/6/) :o)

Mostly it's based on developer's experience and feelings. As for me, Domain Model is applicable for not many systems, for most of them less complicated patterns should be used. May be, it's you case. Well-designd table module application can have "liner" complexity for many and many years and this is ok. But if you feel, that you spend much time on doing the same job for different parts/classes/modules of your application, if you feel, you can't control it, if you have distributed team and 10-20 developers, you can think about separation of concerns, bounded context and domain model.
So, this diagram is mostly marketing step to "sell" you DDD. I like DDD, but it really takes a lot of time at the beginning and there is a chance, that you never reach time, when DDD will be easier than any non DDD-way.

So, answering your question - no reason, just to tell that **sometimes** DDD is better.

Comment: So, this diagram is mostly marketing step to "sell" you DDD.>>> lol

Comment: @RıfatErdemSahin every time I see it, I have such feelings :)